# WebView autofill is disabled because WebView isn't created with activity context

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Independently from what solutions I keep having this log:

> W/cr_AwAutofillManager: WebView autofill is disabled because WebView isn't created with activity context.

1. Why is this log appearing? I don't find any example of this online.
2. Is there any way to solve this / use autofill without JavaScript?

I don't have much experience with android and I have tried some tweaks such as calling `setImportantForAutofill()` and `setAutofillHints` and other method calls referring autofill.

Java code of **`LoginApplication.java`** (extends `AppCompatActivity`):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MainApplication.getMyComponent().inject(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    WebView loginWebView = findViewById(R.id.weblogin);

    loginWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebClient(storage, keycloakService, this));
    WebSettings webSettings = loginWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    loginWebView.loadUrl(authCodeUrl.toString());
}
```

XML code of **`activity_login.xml`**:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".auth.LoginApplication">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/weblogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

XML code of **`AndroidManifest.xml`**:

```
<activity
    android:name=".auth.LoginApplication">
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="com.criticalsoftware.pulsar.android.client"
            android:path="/oauth2redirect"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```